# Remember me service in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am getting this log on console :

> [UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor] RememberMeServices is
>   not an instance of AbstractRememberMeServices. UserDetailsService will
>   not be automatically injected.

Can anyone tell me why this? I think this might create a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details, add code snippets, configuration details, etc. Which version of Spring Security you're using?

Comment: Migration from Spring security 2 to 3

Comment: Is your RememberMeServices a subclass of AbstractRememberMeServices?

Comment: no, I have written my own. similar to AbstractRememberMeServices and also implements  LogoutHandler, RememberMeServices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an informational message and does not mean there is a problem. If your custom implementation of `RememberMeServices` extends `AbstractRememberMeServices` and you are using the `<remember-me/>` element Spring Security will automatically inject an instance of the `UserDetailsService` for you. This means if you are creating a custom `RememberMeServices` that requires a `UserDetailsService` and you have not extended `AbstractRememberMeServices` you must explicitly wire it. If the custom `RememberMeServices` does not require a `UserDetailsService` you can safely ignore this log statement (it is at INFO level not error level).